# Calling controller within controller in Angular

Tags: angularjs

I have a popup controller:

```
@PopupController = ["$scope", ($scope) ->
  $scope.isActive = false

  $scope.open = ->
    $scope.isActive = true

]
```

And teachers controller:

```
@TeachersController = ["$scope", "Teacher", ($scope, Teacher) ->
  $scope.teachers = Teacher.query()

  $scope.showTeacher = ->
    # somehow call PopupController.open()

]
```

How to call `PopupController.open()` from `TeachersController`?

Or maybe I'm doing it wrong and Angular has some better ways to implement it?

Comment: Could you transform your Popup controller as a Popup service?

Comment: @jpmorin now the Popup controller is binded to the view with `ng-controller` attr. How can I bind the service in the same way?

Comment: You most likely should be using a directive instead of a controller... But that is just based on the name.  Controllers shouldn't have DOM manipulation, and there should be no reason to call a controller from within a controller.  A service could be a go-between, but again, if you are trying to open a pop-up on the page, a directive is what you need.

Comment: First of all, it is possible for two controllers to communicate with each other **only if** they use a common service or one is prototypal descendent of the other. But for your case, I agree with @TimWithers that the popup functionality shouldn't be viewed as a controller but a directive because it involves DOM manipulation. A good starting point is to take a look of how the [AngularUI Bootstrap project](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) implemented their _Dialog_ and _Model_ directives.

Comment: If either of the directives suites your need, you can choose to simply adopt it or implement your own directive while using their source code as reference.

Answer (score 3):

You may use [$broadcast](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope#%24broadcast) (downward to child scopes) or $emit (upward to scope hierarchy) to transmit an event form one controller to the other.

Then you would register an event on the receiver that triggers your function. See [http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope#$on](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope#%24on).